# how to remove digital signature from excel workbook in Excel2010 without prompts using Excel API

Tags: excel-2010, digital-signature, prompt

In Excel 2007, I used to invoke SaveAs on workbook to do that. But in Excel,2010 things are different.

Once i invoke SaveAS on a workbook, then signatures get invaidated, but the file is then opened in Readonly mode. Now once i make attempt to make it editable (by putting Final=False), then MSExcel throws follwoing prompt: Signatures removed and document has been saved.

Is there a way to get rid of this prompt in Excel 2010??